# Active Class and Hover Border Causing Image in List of Link to Skip Out of Grid in HTML and CSS using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is the link to the website in question: [http://shortpoet.github.io](https://shortpoet.github.io)

It is being built for a class.  I have tried asking the TAs and Professor for help and no one seems to be able to explain the unexpected behavior.  I have searched for possible answers including:

- setting min/max height for containing divs
- using img-thumbnail class
- changing the col size and grid structure
- changing the border size (only eliminating the border works but that defeats
  the purpose of the feature I am trying to build
- changing the padding
- maybe even other things I am not thinking of right now, I have tried everything I can think of and Google

I am trying to surround the active link/image of one out or four plots in a square grid with a border.  I also have a border that surrounds the :hover element.  There are five pages in which I use the cluster of images as links.  The grid is broken in all except 'humidity' in slightly different ways.  In all cases the fourth image 'wind speed' is shifted to another row.  In all cases hovering over the 'humidity' image resets the grid to its proper place, or when there is a permanent border on that image because it is currently active.

I will include a small snippet of code for the specific area.  As the link is included above, it should be feasible to test the behavior.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">            
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <section id="visualizations">
                  <h3 class="text-center">Visualizations</h3>
                  <hr>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">        
                      <a class="active" href="temperature.html">
                        <img class="img-responsive active" src="assets/images/Fig1.png" alt="Scatter plot of City Latitude vs Temperature in degrees Fahrenheit">
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">     
                      <a href="humidity.html">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/Fig2.png" alt="Scatter plot of City Latitude vs Humidity">
                      </a>
                    </div>        
                    <div class="col-xs-6">           
                      <a href="cloudiness.html">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/Fig3.png" alt="Scatter plot of City Latitude vs Cloudiness">                     
                      </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                      <a href="windSpeed.html">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/Fig4.png" alt="Scatter plot of City Latitude vs Wind Speed">
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I am including most of the CSS for good measure...

```
/* Large desktops and laptops */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

}

/* Landscape tablets and medium desktops */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

}

/* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

}

/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
@media (max-width: 767px) {

}

/* Portrait phones and smaller */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    /*body {
        background-color: silver;
    }*/
}

body {
    background-color: silver;
    padding: 1% 0% 13% 0%;
}

.navcolor {
    background-color: #6EB25A;
    color: #5A5AB2 !important;
}
.navborder {
    border: #ffab80 1px solid;
}

.all {
    color: #6EB25A;
    background-color: #5A5AB2;
    border: #ffab80 solid 1px;
    padding: 3%;
}

#title {
    position: relative;
    right: 17%;
}

#comparison #title {
    position: inherit;
}

#comparison, hr {
    width: 100%;
}

h1 {
    color: #6EB25A;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
hr {
    border-color: #ffab80
}

hr.specialtest {
    margin: 0 0px 0 37px;
    width: 90%;
}

hr.special {
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 37px;
    width: 90%;
}

.box {
    color: #6EB25A;
    background-color: #5A5AB2;
    /*border: 3px #FFAB80 solid;
    border-radius: 35%;*/
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*width: 500px;*/
    height: auto;
    padding: 0% 0%;
}

#image, h4 {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 2% 0% 0% 0%;
}

#image {
    border-top: #ffab80 solid 2px;
    border-left: #ffab80 solid 2px;
    border-right: #ffab80 solid 2px;
}

#index #image {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 30px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#index h4 {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 13.5%;
}

#index #analysis hr {
    width: 300px;
}

#index #analysis {
    padding: 2% 5%;
}

#index p {
    padding: 0 !important;
    line-height: 200%;
}

#mainbox {
    padding: 1% 5%;
}

#visualizations img:hover {
    border: #ffab80 2px solid;
}

nav a:hover {
    border: #ffab80 2px solid;
}

#analysis {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: #ffab80 solid 2px;
    border-left: #ffab80 solid 2px;
    border-right: #ffab80 solid 2px;
}

#temperature #analysis {
    background-color: white;
    border-left: #ffab80 solid 2px;
    border-right: #ffab80 solid 2px;
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
}

#testrow {
    max-height: 317px;
}

#analysis, h4 {
    padding: .5% 0% 0% 0%;
}

#analysis p {
    padding: 2% 13% 5% 13%;
}

#map {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: #ffab80 solid 2px;
    border-left: #ffab80 solid 2px;
    border-right: #ffab80 solid 2px;
}

#map, h4 {
    padding: .5% 0% 0% 0%;
}

#map p {
    padding: 2% 13% 5% 13%;
}

#map img {
    padding: 2%;
}

#visualizations {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 2% 1% 5% 1%;
}

#visualizations hr {
    width: 90%;
}

#image hr {
    width: 90%;
}

img {
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90% !important;
}

img.active {
    border: #5A5AB2 2px solid;
}

.line {
    display: inline-block;
}

.center {
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-spacing: 5px; /* why won't this apply ? */
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
}

.bulletproof {
    list-style-type: none;
}

/*body {
    background-color: silver;
}*/

/* Pagination links */
.pagination a {
    color: #6EB25A;
    float: left;
    padding: 21px 211px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color .3s;
    border: #ffab80 1px solid;
  }

  /* Style the active/current link */
  .pagination a.active {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
  }

  /* Add a grey background color on mouse-over */
  .pagination a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #ddd;}
```

Please excuse any errors in this post and direct me to best practices as it is my first.  I tried using the code button but not sure it is gonna work.  Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so you need to add a new row between your first two and last two col-xs-6. Your general structure should look like the following:

```
<section id="visualizations">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
  </div>  
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you Eric!! That was it.  Always seems so simple once you have the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You may add a transparent border to inactive images, so that the size remains the same when the border is visible, a CSS only solution could be this:

```
#visualizations a img {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
#visualizations a img.active {
    border: 2px solid #5A5AB2;
}
#visualizations a img:hover {
    border: 2px solid #FFAB80;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Daniele!  I was wondering about this actually.  I tried adding a special class with display: none but that hid the whole image.  Good to know about 'transparent' border :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the frame has a very tight width, and when you place the 2px border, there is no more element on the same line and gives this problem in some elements.

If you do not want to mess around much in the structure, you can edit this part of your CSS:

```
img.active {
border: #5A5AB2 2px solid;
width: calc(100% - 2px); /*add this line*/
}
```

That way it decreases 2px wide in this element when it is with that class. I used the CSS method of calc to set only 2px to less.

(I tested it directly on your site by the element inspector and it worked)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This practice also happened to me recently, but it is quite simple using CSS. You simply have to generate a transparent color border beforehand and so when you modify its color with :hover you simply have to change its color. I share the code to my method:

```
nav a {
    border: transparent 2px solid;
}
nav a:hover {
    border-color: #ffab80;
}
```

To solve, simply separate the pairs of images by rows to correctly separate the content and do not misfit. I enclose

```
<section id="visualizations">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>  
</section>
```